# Find exact match in column of list

Tags: python, pandas, list

How could I create exactly_in_colb? It checks if any item in lookfor is exactly in colb

```
lookfor = ["ap", "bana", "pear", "taste"]

df   col      colb
0   apple     ["app", "pl"]
1   banana    ["bana"]
2   pear      ["pear"]
```

Expected Output

```
df   col      colb                    exactly_in_colb
0   apple     ["app", "pl"]      
1   banana    ["bana", "yellow"]        ["bana"]
2   pear      ["pear", "taste"]        ["pear", "taste"]
```

Pandas thinks colb is an np.array. If I convert it to string, the code runs but won't look for exact matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `set.intersection`:

```
lookfor = ["ap", "bana", "pear", "taste"]

df['exactly_in_colb'] = df['colb'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x).intersection(lookfor)))
print (df)
   df     col           colb exactly_in_colb
0   0   apple      [app, pl]              []
1   1  banana         [bana]          [bana]
2   2    pear  [pear, taste]   [pear, taste]
```

Comment: how could I remove empty lists and put "" instead? I tried writing a function if len>0, put np. Nan and then fillna. But then I am getting None instead

Comment: @asd - sure, use `df['colb'] = df['colb'].where(df['colb'].astype(bool), '')`

Comment: I seem to be getting a None Type not iterable error

Comment: @asd Do you add code `df['colb'] = df['colb'].where(df['colb'].astype(bool), '')` after my solution?

Comment: I wrote a new q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74106762/search-column-of-lists

Answer (score 1):

You need a list comprehension and set lookup (for efficiency):

```
lookfor = ["ap", "bana", "pear", "taste"]
# make a set for efficient lookup
S = set(lookfor)

# looping through list to keep original order
df['exactly_in_colb'] = [[v for v in l if v in S] for l in df['colb']]
```

output:

```
      col            colb  exactly_in_colb
0   apple       [app, pl]               []
1  banana          [bana]           [bana]
2    pear   [pear, taste]    [pear, taste]
```

Comment: Have you tested this approach? Unlike using a direct conversion to set, this keeps the original order