# Search column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a df with a col of a list of strings. I want to create `col_I_want` of exact matches.

```
lookfor=["apple", "nectarine"]
```

```
      col                              col_I_want
0   ["apple", "banana", "nectarine"]   ["apple", "nectarine"]
1   ["pear", "banana"]                 np.NaN
```

If I do the below, I get `numpy array object has no attribute apply` error.

```
df['col'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x).intersection(lookfor)))
```

If I do the below, I get  `pd.Series.__iter__() is not implemented` since I'm using Pandas on Spark

```
ps.series(df['col']).apply(lambda x: list(set(x).intersection(lookfor)))
```

I could convert the column to string but that would make it harder to find exact matches.

Comment: `numpy array object has no attribute apply` - so it means `df` is array? Is possilbe see complete code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change solution for custom function for `NaN` if no match:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [['apple', 'banana', 'nectarine'], ['pear', 'banana']]})

lookfor=["apple", "nectarine"]

def f(x):
    y = list(set(x).intersection(lookfor))
    return np.nan if len(y) == 0 else y
    

df['col_I_want'] = df['col'].apply(f)
print (df)
                          col          col_I_want
0  [apple, banana, nectarine]  [nectarine, apple]
1              [pear, banana]                 NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

One can do that with [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) and a custom lambda function as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
    
df['col_I_want'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i.lower() in [j.lower() for j in lookfor]] if len([i for i in x if i.lower() in [j.lower() for j in lookfor]]) > 0 else np.NaN)

[Out]:

                          col          col_I_want
0  [apple, banana, nectarine]  [apple, nectarine]
1              [pear, banana]                 NaN
```

One can also do it with a list comprehension as follows

```
df['col_I_want'] = [ [i for i in x if i.lower() in [j.lower() for j in lookfor]] if len([i for i in x if i.lower() in [j.lower() for j in lookfor]]) > 0 else np.NaN for x in df['col'] ]

[Out]:

                          col          col_I_want
0  [apple, banana, nectarine]  [apple, nectarine]
1              [pear, banana]                 NaN
```

**Notes:**

- `.lower()` is a way to make it case insensitive.
- The second if is a way to then fill the empty column with a [`numpy.NaN`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.NAN).